What is the point of studying non-autonomous ODEs?
Any ordinary differential equation can be transformed into an equivalent autonomous system. For example, $x'(t) = f(t, x(t))$ is equivalent to $X'(t) = F(X(t))$ with $X(t):=(t, x(t))$ and $F(s,z) := (1, f(s,z))$.
Why is ODE solution theory focused on non-autonomous equations? Would it not be simpler if we asumed that the ODE is always autonomous?

What's the point of studying the quadratic equation $b x^2+cx+d=0$? Any quadratic equation can be written as a cubic equation $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ just taking $a=0$, so why don't we just study cubic equations?

One possible point is that the minimal hypothesis to have a ``well-behaved'' non-autonomous ODE are weaker with respect to the ones for autonomuous ODE, concerning the dependence on the time variable. Indeed, you just nead Lebesgue measurability in $t$ (plus some boundedness hypothesis, see Caratheodory existence theorem). When you consider the time as an additional state variable, the corresponding vector field is not Lipschitz...so, in a sense, it is not true that ''Any ordinary differential equation can be transformed into an equivalent autonomous system''...

@MatteoDR ok, so the problem is that the non-autonomous ODE and its autonomous are not really „equivalent“, or maybe that they are only equivalent in the sense that, if y(t) is a solution of the non-autonomous ODE, then Y(t):=(t, y(t)) is a solution of the autonomous one, and viceversa.

Also the mentioned ''equivalence'' you are referring about is questionable, since we have to agree what ''solution'' means: a solution has to be continuous/differentable a.e. etc?
More generally, I would say it is important/interesting to look at the variable $t$ as a special one (and not just as an additional ''position'' with a derivative constant and equal to $1$), when talking about the ''behaviour'' of solutions: notions as invariance/stability/limiting sets,(and many others) are not ''conserved well'' when you do the ''autonomous-zation'' you mentioned...

Ok, I think I get it. Thank you for your help!

@jjagmath Now I get your point. The conversion into an autonomous equation does not necessarily make it less complex.
